# Is there any way to install a transient package?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line, apt

Using a live linux distribution we can install some package , it is not a persistent install, the package will be removed next boot.

On a fully installed system, is there any command line tool or an `apt` configuration allowing a non-persistent install?

Comment: A script uninstalling the package, executed at boot/reboot is out of the question?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I am looking for a command line tool. or `apt` option/configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the `apt` side of things goes, I’m not aware of anything; in fact `apt` and `dpkg` go out of their way to ensure that the system remains in a consistent state, and that as far as possible, changes made to the package selection *are* “permanent” (at least until the next `apt` or `dpkg` invocation).

There is something you could do to get you part of the way: install the package, then mark it as automatically installed (`apt-mark auto`). That way, if nothing else depends (even weakly) on the package, it will be removed the next time you run `apt autoremove`.

I don’t know about “any command line tool”, but who knows, there might well be something out there. One could consider that `debootstrap` in a `tmpfs`-based chroot counts as a temporary installation, but I don’t think that’s really what you’re looking for!